# How can I add a column tracking who last changed another column, so a modified column for a column

Tags: column, calculated-column

I need to track who mast modified specific columns, and would like to display this name in a column within the list. So within the list Column A would be Fix complete and Column B would be Fix completed by. Column C would be Test complete and Column D would be Test completed by. Column B should tell me who added/modified the data in Column A. Column D should tell me who added/modified the data in Column C. I'm using SP 2007.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Do all of your updating of the list using a workflow which updates the columns in pais
2. Create an EventReceiver for the ItemUpdating event which updates the xxx By columns correspoding to changes. See [Everything you need to know about Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) Event Handlers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx)